# Create a form for uploading images

Tags: forms, file-upload, symfony1

I want to let users upload images from their drives. Searching around the net, here's what I've found :

The form :

```
class ImageForm extends BaseForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->setWidget('file', new sfWidgetFormInputFileEditable(
      array(
        'edit_mode'=>false,
        'with_delete' => false,
        'file_src' => '',
        )
    ));

    $this->setValidator('file', new sfValidatorFile(
      array(
        'max_size' => 500000,
        'mime_types' => 'web_images',
        'path' => '/web/uploads/assets',
        'required' => true
        //'validated_file_class' => 'sfValidatedFileCustom'
        )

    ));

  }
}
```

the action :

```
  public function executeAdd(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->form = new ImageForm();

    if ($request->isMethod('post'))
      if ($this->form->isValid())
      {
           //...what goes here ?
      }

  }
```

the template :

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('@images_add') ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/data">
<?php echo $form['file']->renderError() ?>
<?php echo $form->render(array('file' => array('class' => 'file'))) ?>
<input type="submit" value="envoyer" />
</form>
```

Symfony doesn't throw any errors, but nothing is transfered. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre missing an impotant part which is binding the the values to the form:

```
  public function executeAdd(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->form = new ImageForm();

    if ($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
      // you need to bind the values and files to the submitted form
      $this->form->bind(
        $request->getParameter($this->form->getName())
        $request->getFiles($this->form->getName())
      );

      // then check if its valid - if it is valid the validator 
      // should save the file for you
      if ($this->form->isValid())
      {
           // redirect, render a different view, or set a flash message
      }

    }
  }
```

However, you want to make sure you set the name format for your form so you can grab a the values and files in the fashion... In your configure method you need to call `setNameFormat`:

```
public function configure()
{
   // other config code

   $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('image[%s]');
}
```

Also in `configure` you dont need to call `parent::setUp()`... That is called automatically and is actually what invokes the `configure` method.

LAstly, you ned to have to correct markup - your emissing the form name from your tag:

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('@images_add') ?>" name="<?php echo $form->getName() ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/data">
```

Personally I like to use the form object to generate this as well as it looks cleaner to my eyes:

```
<?php echo $form->renderFormTag(
  url_for('@images_add'),
  array('method' => 'post') // any other html attriubutes
) ?>
```

It will work out the encoding and name attributes based on how youve configured the form.

Comment: Yup. @Manu, you'll also find a complete example of how to do this, including binding the values, in Chapter 10 of the "Jobeet" Practical Symfony tutorial. For [Propel](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Propel/en/10) or [Doctrine](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10)

Comment: I must have made a mistake somewhere, validating the form fails, saying that file is required.

Comment: well i see now in what you posted your widget is `file` and your validator is `filename` they need to be the same thing whatever you choose..

Comment: Now the form validates but nothing is uploaded

Comment: hum. the form doesn't show errors when I use $form->renderFormTag

Comment: hmm maybe it only saves aouto matically with model driven forms... try calling `$form->getValue($yourFileWidgetKey)->save();` inside your validation if statement.

Comment: you may be on to something.. now it says "Failed to create file upload directory"

Comment: now all I need is to keep the original filename and move the uploaded file

Comment: => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943259/how-to-let-the-user-choose-the-upload-directory